# Feeding Multiline STDIN Input to Command

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a script that outputs git repository SSH URLs, like this:

```
git@example.com:namespace/project.git
git@example.com:another_namespace/some_other_project.git
```

I want to run the command `git clone` (or other commands) for each line.

I tried piping it to `xargs`, but I either get the output in one line, or a multi line input dumped to a single command.

How do you run an arbitrary command on each line via a pipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, you can do this just using a `while` loop in bash (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7045517/808870)):

```
<whatever your command/output is> | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

Where `echo` is your command and using `$line` as the output for each line, which you can adjust as-needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's a bit tricky, but let me show you this example:

Here's the test data

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
```

Here's what you tried (I guess)

```
$ cat a | xargs echo foo
foo 1 2 3
```

Here's how to make it work using `xargs`:

```
$ cat a | xargs -I '{}' echo foo '{}'
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
```

So instead of just piping a list of the URLs to `xargs git clone`, try defining the placeholder (`-I '{}'`) and tell xargs what to do with it (`git clone '{}'`).